# Heremaps component not loading properly within Vuetify's <v-tab> <v-window-item>

Tags: vue.js, heremaps, vuetifyjs3

I am integrating the Heremaps component into my Vue.js application using the Vuetify framework. However, I'm encountering an issue where the heremaps component is not loading properly when wrapped within  components. Interestingly, the maps only load correctly when I manually inspect the page.

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab">
  <v-tab value="map">Map</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
<v-window v-model="tab">
  <v-window-item value="map"> <heremap/> </v-window-item>
</v-window>
```

Ensure that the Heremaps component works correctly when not wrapped within `<v-window>` and `<v-window-item>`.
Verify that all necessary heremaps dependencies and scripts are properly included.
Check for any console errors or warnings, but no relevant errors are reported.

[You can try it here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuetify-starter-qcckaz?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: In your stackblitz, the sources from js.api.here.com are not loaded due to cross-origin resource policy. Not sure why, I thought this does not affect scripts unless you opt-in. Don't know if it is a stackblitz thing.